# How to set default state for React toggle custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash

So the scenario is once I click a chevron button, an accordion component which placed right underneath of the chevron button opens and shows its children components.

However I don't want other chevron buttons share same state so that only a clicked chevron button with a related accordion expands.

And by default once the template component has just mounted, accordions expand showing its children with chevron buttons are up `^`

codes:

```
// useChevron hook

import { useState } from 'react';


const useChevron = () => {
  const [isChevronUp, setIsChevronUp] = useState<Partial<any>>({});


  const handleChevron = (id: string) => {
    setIsChevronUp((previousState) => ({
      ...previousState,
      [id]: !previousState[id],
    }));
  };

  return { isChevronUp, setIsChevronUp, handleChevron };
};

export default useChevron;
```

```
// template
...
const { handleChevron, isChevronUp } = useChevron();
...

<div id="containerOne">

// when it has just been rendered isChevronUp is empty object so in case set isOpen as true which makes chevron looks like ^ and shows accordion's children
<ChevronButton
            isOpen={_.isEmpty(isChevronUp) ? true : !!isChevronUp.containerOne} 
            id='containerOne'
            onClick={() => handleChevron('containerOne')}
          />
</div>
<Accordion isOpen={_.isEmpty(isChevronUp) ? true : !!isChevronUp.containerOne}>
<ChildrenComponent1 />
<ChildrenComponent2 />
...
```

It seems like working except I have to click twice the chevron button at very first time then toggling fine as expected.

I tried below:

```
const [isChevronUp, setIsChevronUp] = useState<Partial<SomeType>>({
      'default': true
});
...

<ChevronButton
            isOpen={Object.keys(isChevronUp).length === 1 ? isChevronUp.default : !!isChevronUp.containerOne} 
            id='containerOne'
            onClick={() => handleChevron('containerOne')}
          />
</div>
<Accordion isOpen={Object.keys(isChevronUp).length === 1 ? isChevronUp.default : !!isChevronUp.containerOne}>
```

but it's the same having to click the chevron button twice.

What is the best way to set defualt chevron up and accordion expanded in this situation and solve the twice clicking stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try change condition to `Object.keys(isChevronUp).length > 0 ? !!isChevronUp.containerOne : isChevronUp.default` or `Object.keys(isChevronUp).length > 0 ? !!isChevronUp.containerOne : true`

Comment: There will be only one accordion or will it be dynamic ?

Comment: @Shyam there are multiple accordions must be dynamic

Comment: @footlessbird so what should be the initial open state of the accordions ? should it be true or false ?

Comment: @footlessbird Also you can add an **initialization function** for chevrons hook, where you will create a field with a key equal to the chevron id and a value equal to true by default. Then you can just get the chevron value without a condition

Comment: @wowandy tried both but no luck

Comment: @Shyam it should be true

Comment: @wowandy I will appreciate it, if you can provide a small reproduction

Comment: @footlessbird can you provide a code sandbox ? i can work on top of it .

Comment: @footlessbird added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68926157/16593275)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an **initialization function** for chevrons hook, where you will create a field with a key equal to the chevron id and a value equal to true by default. Then you can just get the chevron value without a condition

```tsx
// useChevron hook

import { useState } from 'react';

const useChevron = () => {
  const [isChevronUp, setIsChevronUp, initChevron] = useState<Partial<any>>({});

  const init = (id: string) => {
    setIsChevronUp((previousState) => ({
      ...previousState,
      [id]: true,
    }));
  };

  const handleChevron = (id: string) => {
    setIsChevronUp((previousState) => ({
      ...previousState,
      [id]: !previousState[id],
    }));
  };

  return { isChevronUp, setIsChevronUp, handleChevron, init };
};

export default useChevron;

// template
...
const { handleChevron, isChevronUp, init } = useChevron();

useEffect(() => {
  init('containerOne');
}, []);
...

<div id="containerOne">

// when it has just been rendered isChevronUp is empty object so in case set isOpen as true which makes chevron looks like ^ and shows accordion's children
<ChevronButton
            isOpen={isChevronUp.containerOne} 
            id='containerOne'
            onClick={() => handleChevron('containerOne')}
          />
</div>
<Accordion isOpen={isChevronUp.containerOne}>
<ChildrenComponent1 />
<ChildrenComponent2 />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `isChevronUp` state hook value, it does not tell you if the specified chevron is selected but contains an object of the selected chevrons.

As such, `isChevronUp` should be a function that you call, or you should check the state accordingly using the `id` string of your chevron

```
// useChevron hook

import { useState } from 'react';


const useChevron = () => {
  const [chevronState, setChevronState] = useState<Partial<any>>({});


  const handleChevron = (id: string) => {
    setChevronState((previousState) => ({
      ...previousState,
      [id]: !previousState[id],
    }));
  };

  const isChevronUp = (id: string) => Boolean(chevronState[id]);

  return { isChevronUp, handleChevron };
};

export default useChevron;
```

And when you check if it's open do:

```
<ChevronButton
  isOpen={isChevronUp('containerOne')}
...
```

something like that

Comment: well, it is matter of default look, I actually have done simply like `isOpen={!!isChevronUp.containerOne}` for both ChevronButton and Accordion with no useChevron hook change but the matter is again in case the chevron is down and accordion is closed when it just has rendered which is completely opposite to what I wanted